# get_posts() by category + custom select fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a two 'select' custom fields for my posts, titled author_1 and author_2. Below are the possible values in each of these select fields.

```
testauthor1 : Test Author 1
testauthor2 : Test Author 2
testauthor3 : Test Author 3
```

Each selection has both a value and a label. I want my get_posts() query to find all posts where the page title is the label for the currently selected value. For instance.. if I have a post where author_1 = "testauthor2 : Test Author 2" and the current page title is "Test Author 2", that post should be returned.

Currently, my query is just returning all posts in category 9, but it's not returning posts ONLY where author_1 or author_2 is equal to the current page title.

```
function hide_cotw_heading(){
    $title = get_the_title();
    $args = array(
        'cat' => 9,
        'meta_query'    => array(
            'relation'      => 'OR',
            array(
                'meta_key'       => 'author_1',
                'meta_label'     => $title
            ),
            array(
                'meta_key'       => 'author_2',
                'meta_label'     => $title
            )
        )
      );
      
      $latest_posts = get_posts( $args );
      if($latest_posts){
        return print_r($latest_posts);
      } else{
        return 'No posts';
      }
}
```

Comment: Because it's `key` and `value` not `meta_key` and `meta_label`. `meta_key` is only used **outside** of the `meta_query` array and `meta_label` isn't a valid array index.

Comment: I originally had key and value, but that wasn't working either - all posts were being returned still. I've tried numerous variations but they all yield the same result. Is it not possible to query posts by a label?

Comment: That's fine that you had `key` and `value` originally, but your question does not contain that information, so it appears as a typo question. The biggest issue that appears looking at your question again - I'm assuming that the value for `meta_key` `author_1/2` - is the entire string `testauthor3 : Test Author 3` - if that's the case, that's **not a value/key** pair. That's just a string, so there's no such thing as a `label`. What you can try is add `'compare' => 'LIKE'` to the meta_query arrays. Like `array ( 'key' =>  'author_1', 'value' => $title, 'compare' => 'LIKE')